# How to fix "cannot lock ref" error while deploying on server using capistrano?

Tags: git, capistrano

I was trying to deploy a hotfix to my staging server (DigitalOcean) but got a "cannot lock ref" error. I stumbled on this error before. I had a branch 'hotfix' and then I created 'hotfix/some-hotfix' branch and when I tried to push it to origin I got the error. I fixed it by deleting branch 'hotfix' in my repository (BitBucket). But now I am getting it while deploying on staging server.

Stack trace:

```
SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 1
git stdout: Fetching origin
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/hotfix/my-hotfix-branch-name': 'refs/heads/hotfix' exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/hotfix/my-hotfix-branch-name'
From bitbucket.org:username/repo-name
! [new branch] hotfix/my-hotfix-branch-name -> hotfix/my-hotfix-branch-name (unable to update local ref)
error: some local refs could not be updated; try running
'git remote prune origin' to remove any old, conflicting branches
error: Could not fetch origin
git stderr: Nothing written
```

I tried running `git remote prune origin` but it didn't help.
I'm stuck with no ideas here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue doing this:

1. `ssh` to your server.
2. Find `/repo/` folder (I got mine in my deployed application folder `~/apps/app-name/repo`) and `cd` into it.
3. Run `git remote prune origin`.

After making this steps I was able to deploy to my server.

Answer (score 5):

While branch names are *mostly* just strings—so `hotfix` and `hotfix/my-hotfix-branch-name` are just the obvious, i.e., two different names—parts of Git insist (for reasons both good and bad) on treating them like directory and file name components.

(Note: if you are on Windows, you can mentally substitute `/` with `\` here.  Or, just realize that `a/b` works just as well on Windows as `a\b`, for almost all purposes.)

If you have a *file* named `README`, your OS won't let you create another file named `README/TOO`.  That is, the entity-slot `README` is taken up by "file entity".  You must first remove or rename `README`, then create a *directory* (or folder, if you prefer that term) named `README`.  Inside this directory (or folder) you can now create more files, or move the original `README` file into that directory.

Git imposes the *exact same restrictions* on branch names, and on remote-tracking names.  If there is an existing branch named `hotfix` you cannot create one named `hotfix/my-hotfix-branch-name`.  You fixed this in *your* repository by first deleting `hotfix`.  You must do the same thing in *every other Git repository you intend to use:* if it has a `hotfix`, delete it.  Then you can have that other Git repository create `hotfix/my-hotfix-branch-name`.

It looks like your staging server has a `hotfix` branch in it.  You may have to log in to your staging server directly, or you may be able to use a `git push --delete` to send a delete request to it.  Either way, you must get *that* Git to delete that branch name.  Operations done on your own repository don't help because every repository is independent.

When the problem occurs in a local repository, but due to remote-tracking names like `origin/dir/file`, running `git fetch -p origin` or `git remote prune origin` should fix the problem.  Both the `-p` option to `fetch`—which can be spelled `--prune`—and the `prune` subcommand for `git remote` tell your Git to *remove* remote-tracking names, such as `origin/dir`, that existed because the server had (emphasis on past tense here) a branch named `dir`, but since then, someone deleted that branch.  Your remote-tracking names are your Git's way of remembering what their branches were the last time you talked to them.  So they *had* a `dir` branch, but they no longer have one; now they have a `dir/file` branch.  You must have your Git delete your `origin/dir` before your Git can create an `origin/dir/file` remote-tracking name.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue when I do git pulll

```
> $ git pull 
> error: cannot lock ref
> 'refs/remotes/origin/release/thing_15': 'refs/remotes/origin/release'
> exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/release/thing_15' From
> https://git.mycompany.com/projects/myproject
```

The git fetch fixed it with -p option (which exists in the newer versions of git) , please see the doc here https://git-scm.com/docs/fetch-options/2.20.0#fetch-options--p

```
git fetch -p
```